# Does the bandwidth of a Comcast modem divide if it is connected to two routers on two subnets?

Tags: troubleshooting

I have a 150 megabits/sec Comcast pipe that connects to two subnets through two Cisco routers. The bandwidth at the modem is 150 Mb/s. The bandwidth at one router is 96 Mb/s and the other is 96 Mb/s Neither has the full 150 Mb/s. Does the bandwidth divide into two values, or are the routers causing the reduction in bandwidth?

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you find this a great community to contribute to and learn from. You could improve your question by editing it to add more details. You may find our [Network Engineering Question Checklist](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/292/network-engineering-question-checklist) helpful when editing your question. For example: What are the Cisco router models?  96 Mbps sounds a lot like they only only have 100 Mbps ports.

Answer (score 2):

You have some limitation in your network to 100mb/s as @YLearn said. It is either on the machine interface you are testing, router port or somewhere else.

**A Thumb Rule: A chain is only as strong as its weakest link.**